# Is it possible to add an apt repository before the installer check for dependencies availability?

Tags: deb, packaging, debian

Is it possible to add an apt repository before the installer check for dependencies availability?
I want to add append a deb software repository because the repository contains what's listed in my package's `Depends:` .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is your package and what are its dependencies? ... All package listed in any official repository should be able to satisfy its dependencies from the same repository it's listed in ... So, clarify more please.

Answer (score 1):

You are moving on thin ice, trying to install `.deb` packages that need dependencies not available on your current distribution. It means you are taking package management in your own hands - which is obviously allowed and fine, but which may require significant technical skills from your side and actually may leave you no other option than to compile packages yourself at some point.

Yes, you can add an apt repository before the installer check for dependencies availability. However, there is no guarantee that the repository you want to add will not conflict with your current distribution and eventually break the installation. You can have some confidence that there will be no problems only  when you can find out that PPA you want to add specifically has been prepared and tested to work with your current distribution.